# Composer install git repo into custom path (Wordpress theme)

Tags: wordpress, git, composer-php

I have a custom Wordpress theme hosted on Bitbucket that I'd like installed into the /themes directory in Wordpress when I run `composer install`.

I've played around with different repo 'types' e.g. vcs, package etc and I get errors for everything I've tried so far.

Here's a sample of my (not working) composer.json file:

```
{
  "authors": [
{
  "name": "Joe Bloggs",
  "homepage": "http://www.example.com/"
}
],
 "keywords": [
 "wordpress", "composer", "wp"
],
 "config": {
 "secure-http": false
},
 "repositories": [
  {
   "type": "composer",
   "url": "http://wpackagist.org"
  },
  {
   "type": "package",
   "package": {
    "name": "wordpress/wordpress",
    "version": "4.5.3",
    "type": "webroot",
    "dist": {
      "type": "zip",
      "url": "https://wordpress.org/wordpress-4.5.3.zip"
    },
    "require" : {
      "fancyguy/webroot-installer": "1.1.0"
    }
  }
 },
 {
  "type": "vcs",
  "url": "https://bitbucket.org/gurtfrobe/plunderscores.git"
 }
],
 "require": {
 "php": ">=5.3.2",
 "wordpress/wordpress": "4.5.3",
 "fancyguy/webroot-installer": "1.1.0",
 "composer/installers": "v1.0.12",
 "gurtfrobe/plunderscores": "1.0.1"
},
"extra": {
 "installer-paths": {
  "wp/wp-content/plugins/{$name}/": ["type:wordpress-plugin"],
  "wp/wp-content/mu-plugins/{$name}/": ["type:wordpress-muplugin"],
  "wp/wp-content/themes/{$name}/": ["type:wordpress-theme"]
 },
  "webroot-dir": "wp",
  "webroot-package": "wordpress/wordpress"
 }
}
```

I've also tried the following with no luck:

```
{
  "type": "package",
  "package": {
    "name": "gurtfrobe/plunderscores.git",
    "version": "1.0.1",
    "type": "wordpress-theme",
    "source": {
      "url": "https://bitbucket.org/gurtfrobe/plunderscores.git",
      "type": "vcs",
      "reference": "master"
    }
  }
},
```

Is there a way of achieving this without submitting my theme to wpackagist?

Comment: I think the answer lies [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/how-do-i-install-a-package-to-a-custom-path-for-my-framework.md) somewhere. Haven't yet managed to get it to work mind.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with [this article](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/how-do-i-install-a-package-to-a-custom-path-for-my-framework.md).

Remember to push the latest version tags after you've updated your composer.json file. Otherwise Composer will still try and download a previous version.